# CoreData Multithreading is generating random crashes

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, parent-child

We are following the parent child strategy for saving data in core data.But we are facing some issues like we are not getting data sometime, and some fault values too.

Is there any way to achieve multithreading in core data efficiently.

Comment: yes - this video changed my life - https://vimeo.com/89370886.  It describes and excellent core data setup. It is old, but still relevant.  Much can be now be done with `NSPersistentContainer` but it is all the same basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In multithreading there is an important factor. Things might get done out of the order which you need them to happen so use it carefully. However to use databases i would recommend RealmSwift it is much much faster than core data.